# Curvature and stability

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, curvature, chaos-theory, complex-systems

In Topological methods in hydrodynamics [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSlhQ.png) mentioned that "The Riemannian curvature of a manifold has a profound impact on the behavior of geodesics on it. If the Riemannian curvature of a manifold is positive (as for a sphere or for an ellipsoid), then nearby geodesics oscillate about one another in most cases, and if the curvature is negative (as on the surface of a one-sheet hyperboloid), geodesics rapidly diverge from one another."

[image: Geodesics on manifolds of (a) positive and (b) negative curvatures.^1]

I am curious, if the curvature is positive, but non-constant, does this also imply some kind of stability (eg: Jacobi stability, Lagrange stability or Lyapunov stability) of the geodesics?

I did some research and found that even positive curvature may lead to chaotic phenomena [2]. But I did not find, if it is **positive curvature and non-constant**, what is the **stability of the geodesic**? By the Riemann geometric comparison theorem, We can know that if the positive curvature is bounded, the Jacobi field equation is also bounded, and then there should be no chaos which is conflict with the result of [2](positive curvature may cause chaos). Where did I get it wrong?

---

Example in [2]:

In reference[2] give the 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold (Hénon-Heiles (HH) model) as an example. The curvature tensor has a unique component $R_{1212}$ that is not zero.

The HH Hamiltonian is written in the form
\begin{equation}
        H=\frac{1}{2}\left(p_{1}^{2}+p_{2}^{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(q_{1}^{2}+q_{2}^{2}\right)+q_{1}^{2} q_{2}-\frac{1}{3} q_{2}^{3} .
\end{equation}

It is shown here that chaos in the Hénon-Heiles model stems from parametric instability due to **positive curvature fluctuations** along the geodesics (dynamical motions) of configuration space manifold.

The link between stability and curvature is mathematically expressed by the Jacobi field equation for geodesic spread
\begin{align}
         & \frac{d^{2} \xi_{1}}{d s^{2}}+\frac{1}{2} \mathscr{R} \xi_{1}=0, \\
         & \frac{d^{2} \xi_{2}}{d s^{2}}=0,
\end{align}

If the solution $\xi_{1}(t)$ computed along a given trajectory remains bounded or grows at most linearly with time, then this trajectory is stable. If $\xi_{1}(t)$ grows exponentially with time, then the trajectory is chaotic, i.e., unstable with respect to any variation-even arbitrarily small-of coordinates and momenta operated at any given point of it.

So my question is, why does the positive curvature of an interval, which is non-constant, lead to chaos? This seems to violate the comparison theorem in Riemannian geometry. According to the theorem, the positive curvature is bounded, so $\xi_{1}(t)$ should also be bounded, so why would it grow exponentially? In other words, does the positive curvature of non-constant numbers also imply some kind of stability?

- [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSlhQ.png): Arnold, Vladimir I., and Boris A. Khesin. 2021. Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics. Springer Nature. IV. Differential Geometry of Diffeomorphism Groups in page 214.
- [2]: Casetti, Lapo, Marco Pettini, and E. G. D. Cohen. 2000. “Geometric Approach to Hamiltonian Dynamics and Statistical Mechanics.” Physics Reports 337 (3): 237–341. https://doi.org/10/cmtfhz.

Comment: Comments or some references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Curvature is a local phenomenon, chaos a global one. I don't quite get why the two should be linked this trivially. A system for which all trajectories are constantly diverging can probably not be chaotic, but without that all bets are off, as far as I can tell. What am I missing?

Comment: Standard Newtonian system can be viewed as geodesics of a Riemannian manifold endowed with a suitable metric. The instability of geodesics (mechanical trajectories) are related to curvature through the Jacobi-Levi-Civita (JLC) equation for the evolution of geodesic separation.

Comment: I think this idea is natural(spacetime/curvature effect the motion of matter), but i  don't understand the relationship between curvature fluctuations and chaos(Jacobi field grow exponentially), this seems to violate the comparison theorem in Riemannian geometry(curvature is bounded, Jacobi field equation is also bounded). on the other hand, what is the relationship between positive curvature(especially non-constant positive curvature) and stability of mechanics system?

Comment: I know this, but chaos is about the long term behavior of the system whereas curvature is a point property. What the system does globally is completely unpredictable for all but a handful (literally) of Hamiltonians. It certainly can't be predicted from local curvature properties. A sphere, for instance, has constant positive curvature and all trajectories on it are rock solid and perfectly periodic. Things become a little more rocky on tori.

Comment: Yes. The constant curvature( Sphere or Tori) setting is obviously according Jacobi field.